# Can't load Nokogiri gem when running a .rb file from a text editor, but it works fine in the Ruby command shell

Tags: ruby, text, sublimetext2, scite

I use Scintilla Text Editor and Sublime Text 2.

Whenever I use them to run a Ruby script containing:

```
require 'nokogiri'
```

...I get this error:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- nokogiri (LoadError)
from C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from C:/Users/MY_RUBY_SCRIPT.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and I made sure to require rubygems, but I still got the error.

However, when I run the script from the Command Prompt With Ruby, the script works fine.

Does anyone know why the script fails in text editors, but not in the Command Prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had both Ruby 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 installed, which caused the conflict in SciTE, which was trying to find the gem in Ruby 1.9.2 instead of 1.9.3. I uninstalled 1.9.2 and the script worked fine. If I do need 1.9.2 in the future, I suppose I'll have to learn RVM.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your editor runs a different version of Ruby. You can check by running

```
puts RUBY_VERSION
```

Comment: It's 1.9.2. Hmm, I'm not sure what to do, though. I've never fiddled with a text editor this much yet. Any ideas?

Comment: In your editor's settings, you should be able to adjust the PATH variable. Are you using rvm or something like that?

Comment: I don't think I'm using rvm. Is there a way to tell? I haven't installed it as far as I know. I'm not sure what could have changed in the past week that made the text editors do this

Comment: Ok, different question: how do you manage your different Ruby versions?

Comment: I'm really sorry, padde, I don't know what the question means. As you might guess, I'm pretty new to Ruby (and programming in general).

Comment: If it helps, I just ran the code via SciTE on another computer and it worked just fine.

Comment: It seems you have installed multiple versions of ruby. One way to do so is with rvm, the Ruby Version Manager. If you dont know rvm, you probably arent using it. So, how did you install 1.9.3? Did you have another Ruby version installed before?

Comment: padde, as it turns out, I must've installed 1.9.2 accidentally in recent days. It turns out uninstalling ruby 1.9.2 got the scripts working again. Thanks for your help